# Скорость выполнения MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно каждые 200 миллисекунд очищать таблицу в Mysql и добавлять 5-50 значений. И около 30 компьютеров каждые 0,5 секунды будут подключаться к серверу и запрашивать данные из таблиц.

```
function setBet($games) {
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM bet");
    $sth->execute();

    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO bet(p1_rate,p1_name,p2_rate,p2_name) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
    foreach ($games as $game) {
        $sth->execute(array($game->p1->count, $game->p1->name, $game->p2->count, $game->p2->name));
    }
}
```

Сценарий выполняется более ~0,5 секунд. Как лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Если таблица маленькая и постоянно перезаписывается, сам бог велел выбрать для нее движок MEMORY (HEAP). Он накладывает некоторые ограничения, но попробуйте. Может быть они для вас несущественны. Будет очень-очень быстро.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Не использовать MySQL.

Точнее я хотел сказать что лучше уж смотреть в строну NoSQL.

Хотел написать комментарием, но увы. Весь рейтинг пропал при переносе.

Comment: А, собственно, какие аргументы в пользу NoSQL?

Comment: Обратитесь к @Nicholas Chabanovsky по поводу рейтинга.

Answer (score 0):

Вставляйте по несколько записей сразу, формируя запрос

```
INSERT INTO
    bet(p1_rate,p1_name,p2_rate,p2_name)
VALUES
    ($game->p1->count, $game->p1->name, $game->p2->count, $game->p2->name),
    (2-ые значения),
    (3-и значения),
    ...,
    ();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, оптимизируйте логику в отношении запросов. На вскидку, мне кажется что каждый раз очищать таблицу - накладно, можно пропускать эту процедуру (экономя на этом время) и делать это раз в несколько итераций. Прав я или нет - вам могут показать только тесты. Так что придумывайте - как именно вы можете сэкономить время и как вам это организовать.

Во-вторых, настройте ваш сервер БД таким образом чтобы у вас все операции велись в памяти - выставьте необходимые величины буфферов и т.д. В вашем случае любая операция записи на диск - трата времени. Не буду вам советовать какую именно СУБД выбирать - MySQL или какую-либо другую. Это вам тоже придётся выяснить лично для себя в тестировании, или же исходя из личных предпочтений.

В третьих - продумайте детально архитектуру работы. 30 или сколько там подключающихся компьютеров - вам нужно использовать какую-то технологию чтобы у этих компьютеров 1 раз открывалось подключение и оставалось открытым всё время. Иначе вы просто не сможете получать данные так быстро как вы хотите их получать. Будете вы для этого настраивать Keep-Alive и прочее в настройках веб сервера (Apache или Nginx), или же будете использовать что-то вроде Comet - тоже зависит от вас.

Comment: И да, кстати, если записи обновляются раз в 200мс, а клиенты подключаются раз в 500 мс - уже можно сэкономить на каких-то запросах. Цикл записей - 0, 200, 400, 600, 800мс. А реально для выдачи вам нужны только те, которые приходят на 0 и на 400.

Comment: кто сказал, что запросы придут ровно в Х.000 и Х.500?

Comment: Их можно заставить получать именно эти данные... Если они придут в другой момент - первый раз подождать до нужного времени, а потом всё будет нормально.